# Nestsjs not sending response to NATS server

Tags: microservices, nestjs, nats.io

Hi guys I'm trying to set a Request/response responder(MessagePattern) on a Microservice with NATS in transport layer. I have a natscli subscribing to the server, and from another natscli I'm sending a request, which autogenerates the reply subject(INBOX...), and it's supposed  that returning from nest method should automatically send the response to reply subject, but it's not happening, The natscli which is subscribing the server only records the request.

```
$ nats request test "{\"msg\": \"testingOK\"}" --timeout=20s
13:21:59 Sending request on "test"
nats.exe: error: nats: timeout, try --help
```

My method listening is:

```
@MessagePattern('test')
  getNatsReponse(data: string) {
    return data;
  }
```

And my config is:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(
    AppModule,
    {
      transport: Transport.NATS,
      options: {
        servers: ['nats://nats:4222'],
      },
    },
  );
  app.listen();
}
bootstrap();
```

In docker-compose.yml:

```
nats:
    image: nats
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 4222:4222
    networks:
      - nestjs-network
```

Can somebody tell me what am im doing wrong?